# Store values from input form in MySQL and output them, but can't connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, input

So I'm trying to create a HTML/PHP code that will ask you to order candy bars (Mars, Snickers, Milky way) and then list the receipt of the order, how much it costs, total cost and so on. I did all of that, now I want to store all of the values into MySQL database, and when clicking on order I want to list every order that has been made from the database. I'm trying my best, but just can't figure it out. It gives me error immediately that it can't connect to MySQL database, I'm using WAMP localhost and I created the database and the user and all privileges, tried a hundred times but nothing. don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The error is following:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\MAKEUP2\Q1\order.php on line 34 Call Stack # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010 143072   {main}( )   ..\order.php:0 2    0.0010  144488  mysqli_connect ( )  ..\order.php:34 Connection failed: Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'revetinja'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)

This is the what I have done so far..

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Candy order</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<?php
$mars = $_POST['mars'];
$snickers = $_POST['snickers'];
$milkyway = $_POST['milkyway'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


$marsprice = 1.5;
$snickersprice = 1.7;
$milkywayprice = 1.8;
$totalquantity = $mars + $snickers + $milkyway;
$totalcost = $marsprice * $mars + $snickersprice * $snickers + $milkywayprice * $milkyway;

$marscost = $mars * $marsprice;
$milkycost = $milkyway * $milkywayprice;
$snickerscost = $snickers * $snickersprice;

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "revetinja";
$password = "wrong123";
$dbname = "makeup2";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (item, cost, quantity, total, address)
VALUES ('Mars', '$marsprice', '$mars', '$marscost', '$address')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<div class="container">
<h2>Thank you!</h2>
<p>Your orders for: </p>



<table border-bottom 1px solid grey;>
<tr>
<th width=150 align="center">Item<br>&nbsp;</td>
<th width=100 align="center">Cost<br>&nbsp;</td>
<th width=100 align="center">Quantity<br>&nbsp;</td>
<th align="center" width=100>Total cost<br>&nbsp;</td>

<tr>
<td>Mars</td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $marsprice . ' KM'; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $mars; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $mars * $marsprice . ' KM'; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Snickers</td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $snickersprice . ' KM'; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $snickers; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $snickers * $snickersprice . ' KM'; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Milky ways</td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $milkywayprice. ' KM'; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $milkyway; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $milkyway * $milkywayprice. ' KM'; ?></td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
<td><strong>Total</td>
<td align="left"></td>
<td align="left"><strong><?php echo $totalquantity; ?></td>
<td align="left"><strong><?php echo $totalcost . ' KM'; ?></td>
</tr>
<td>Delivery on: 
<td colspan="6"><?php echo $address; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>were processed.</p>
<a href="order.html" class="btn btn-default" align="center">Go back to orders</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You posted this already earlier, didn't you? Deleted it.

Comment: Rewrote the post again, as it should be, many things were unclear on the old one.

Comment: well, double check your installation and if you've the proper rights/permissions set for that user.

Comment: Can you connect to your local MySQL server via command line?